# Is there a way to run Python code without downloading Python?

Tags: python, executable

My internship has asked me to make my code executable for people who do not have Python downloaded. I can run parts of it on online Python compilers, but it uses different libraries that are not supported on those compilers. My program opens a .csv file specified by the user and filters it and writes the new data to a new .csv file. To implement the code online, I think I would need to learn JavaScript? Is there any other alternative? I appreciate any guidance provided!

Comment: Perhaps your employers are requesting your program be 1. compiled rather than interpreted as a Python script (See the various ways of producing executables for your target platform from Python scripts) or 2. Create a web application which calls your Python service via a RESTful API? Either way, I would suggest you approach your employers for clarification about this task of yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a standalone executable that includes your python script + all necessary files to run it. The users then just run ".exe" file without need to download and setup python environment. A great library to do it is [cx-freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

There is many online python runner. Example `https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/`